# javascript permission/access denied accessing parent non-ssl attributes from an ssl iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, ssl

I understand that to access the parent properties of an iframe it has to be the same domain/scheme/ports, but being this only an ssl/non-ssl issue, is there any workaround?

Comment: Think about what it would mean if there were a security mechanism with a widely-known "workaround" :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. SSL/non-SSL means a different scheme and a different port.

Worse, if you could do this, then all an attacker has to do is inject some code into the non-SSL page, and that could access the SSL data, rendering it insecure.